# Does a guitar ebow work on bass?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar, bow

I am interested in buying an electronic bow, but the one I found is for guitar. **Would this ebow work for my bass?**

The description of the product says:

> E-Bow Plus - handheld **electronic bow for guitar**, replaces the pick in the right hand allowing the guitarist to mimic strings, horns, and woodwinds with unbelievable sensitivity.[...]

Comment: There are loads of examples online of players using ebow on bass; as far as I can tell they are just using regular guitar ebows.

Comment: I have seen many of them as well, but when I looked at the description of the ebow, it said that it was for guitar. I wouldn't want to spend 80 bucks on something that wouldn't work/produce good sound on my bass

Comment: As a matter of personal preference, I encourage a bass player to learn to bow a double bass vs. ebow. The tone (IMHO) is so much more vibrant with a real bow on a string bass (double bass) than an ebow on an electric bass. For me tone is almost everything. But +1 for expanding the universe.

Comment: @filzilla I use a regular bow on my double bass, but I want to try out an ebow for my *electric* one

Comment: I think this is a worthy thing to try, don't let my opinion get in the way of your hands on education. New things should be explored not ignored, kudos to you.

Comment: Ya know -- the ebow web page's FAQ discusses how to deal w/ it on an electric bass!   In the meantime, try using a 1/4" cordless drill (no really, someone does that, sans drill bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reports I've heard are:

1. The grooves in the base of the e-bow do not align with bass strings, thus it is more difficult (though not impossible) to get a steady, consistent placement of the bow at the right location over the string.
2. Due to their thickness, it is more difficult for the ebow to activate the strings; thus you are more likely to need to start off the note by a hammer on.

Despite these, it is possible to use an ebow on a bass, e.g. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A46l07QV3UM), however I'd expect there to be a more difficult learning curve in getting to use it relative to getting it to work well on a guitar, which itself requires dedicated technique practice.

I haven't tried it out myself (maybe the next time I'm with my bass).

Comment: Is that a guitar ebow?

Comment: Nowadays they only make guitar ebows (I have one of the newer, blue-light ones); I've heard rumors that many years ago there was a run of bass specific ebows manufactured, but I've never actually seen one.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic I use mine on guitar and bass. My godfather showed me a trick to make it easier on bass, which was putting some epoxy (~5mm) on either side of the EBow, which was just about perfect for support. Also, I don't have to hammer on with my bass, though it has active pickups which may make a difference.